# instance known in shell gives NameError when used in script?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm afraid I don't understand something basic.  I use python interactively with IPython and I'm running more or less the following script (VPP is a module I wrote with class VPP and class Forecast, they both extend from object).

```
import os
import numpy as np
from VPPP import VPP, Forecast

setup = False
single_run = True

if setup:
    vpp = VPP(foo=foo, bar=bar, ...)  
    forecast = Forecast('my_filename')
    mapping = {'Forecast': 'PConInput.ys[xxx]', 'Price': 'tariffInput.ys[xxx]'}

if single_run:
    fnext = forecast.predict(startday=146, nb_days=2)
    vpp.adapt_forecasts(fnext, mapping)
    vpp.optimize()
```

I have the flags `setup` and `single_run` because the instantiation of vpp takes about 2 minutes, and I want to use the same vpp later in single run with different parameters.

When I run the script with both flags `True`, all is fine. However, when I run again with `setup = False` I get an errormessage: NameError: name 'forecast' is not defined (caused by `fnext = ...`).  However, typing directly in the IPython shell, all instances are known and all commands work fine.

Is this an IPython issue? How can I avoid the instantiation of my vpp object everytime I  want to run my script?

Thanks on beforehand for your answers.
Roel

Comment: How is it that you're using them again in a single run when in your script, they're clearly global variables only used once?

Comment: Actually, there are more commands in `single_run`.  What I want to do is change a few parameters (like startday) and run the series of commands without re-instantiation of the vpp and forecast objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run the script using the IPython `%run` command?

In that case use:

```
In [#]: %run -i filename.py
```

`-i` runs the file in IPython's namespace (instead of an empty one).

For documentation, type `%run?<ENTER>` in IPython.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you start a script in Python it starts with a clean 'slate'. No variables are defined yet, there is not some magic memory Python uses to restore variables created in a previous run of the script.

If you want such behavior you will have to store your variables yourself, e.g. using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) (note this probably won't work if you're communicating with some remote server).

An other solution is to run the script indefinitely and make it do some work every `x` seconds. Or ask for user input:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from VPPP import VPP, Forecast

vpp = VPP(foo=foo, bar=bar, ...)  
forecast = Forecast('my_filename')
mapping = {'Forecast': 'PConInput.ys[xxx]', 'Price': 'tariffInput.ys[xxx]'}

while True:
    try:
        raw_input('Press enter to start. Ctrl-C to exit.')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    fnext = forecast.predict(startday=146, nb_days=2)
    vpp.adapt_forecasts(fnext, mapping)
    vpp.optimize()
```

Now if you press Enter the last three lines will be executed. You can Ctrl-C to exit.

(N.B. for Python 3 change `raw_input` to `input`.)

Comment: I like your suggestion, adapting it to use the raw_input to pass a new startday to the predict() method.  It's probably only useful if I want to change a single parameter, but could come in handy for some cases.